# giving types for expressions

Tags: haskell, types

So I'm being asked to "Give possible types (not involving any type variables) for each
of the following expressions (or else explain why you think the
expression is ill-typed)"
and I'm struggling with the expression 
`[ [], [[]], [[[]]], [[[[]]]], [[[[[    ]]]]] ]`.

When I put `:t *the above expression*` into ghci it tells me that it has the type `[[[[[[a]]]]]]`. I'm confused what the expression is even saying and why it's giving me that type.

Also `:t [ [True], [[]], [[[]]], [[[[]]]], [[[[[]]]]] ]` gives an error, and I don't know why it is ill typed. I think the answer to the first one will help me understand why the second expression fails.

Comment: Hint: what's the type of `[ [], [[]], [[[]]], [[[[]]]], [[[[[ ]]]]], [[[[[True]]]]] ]`? Also, consider why `[True, []]` and `[True, [True]]` are ill-typed.

Comment: I guess I'm kind confused on the meaning of the syntax with all the brackets. The whole thing is a list with the elements a list, a list of lists and so on. I'm not sure why it would take a list of lists of lists of lists of a list with a Bool, and not a list with a Bool. Also how can the whole list have a type [[[[[[]]]]]] when there is also a list and a lists of lists and so on inside the list. (I've written list way too many times now)

Comment: Lists in Haskell have kind `* -> *`, rather than `*` as types like Bool have. If you don't know what kinds are yet, here's the relevant consequence of that: No value in Haskell is just "a list". Instead, values must be "a list of ____s", where the blank must be filled in with something. For example, the type of `[True]` can be stated in words as "a list of Bools", and the type of `[[True]]` can be stated as "a list of lists of Bools". (Just "a list of lists" would not be valid, since the last "list" wouldn't be "of" anything.) Given this, can you figure out the types?

Comment: Okay, so the examples you gave me are invalid because you can't have list of bools and then a list of lists of anything because you already have a list of bools, correct? Why then an we have a list that has a bunch of lists with empty lists at the center, and then have the final list have a True at the center? Shoudn't all the lists have a Bool at the center?

Comment: @csStudent Don't forget to separate the list types `[Bool]` and `[[Bool]]`, and the values `[True]`, `[[True]]`, etc. The value `[]` can be of type `[[Bool]]`, because it is an empty list of lists of bools. `[ [], [True] ]` is a list of lists of bools, where one value is empty and the other contains a single `True` value. `[ [False, False], [], [True] ]` has type `[[Bool]]`, as does `[]` and `[[True]]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand why the expression: `[ [], [[]], [[[]]], [[[[]]]], [[[[[ ]]]]] ]` has type `[[[[[[a]]]]]]`, you need to understand what is the type of `[]` first.

Actually, `[]` is equivalent to `[a']`, where `a'` is type variable without any constraint. That means `a'` can be any type. So, when a list is constructed, say, `[ [], [[]] ]`, it is legal to replace `a'` with `[a]` as:

```
[ [], [[]] ] ~ [ [a'] [[a]] ] ~ [ [[a]], [[a]] ] ~ [ [[a]] ]
```

The same reason why

```
[ [], [[]], [[[]]], [[[[]]]], [[[[[ ]]]]] ] ~  [ [[[[[a]]]]] ]
```

But when you constructs a list as `[ [True], [[]] ]`, there is no way to convert `True` to a list, even though `[a]` can be any type of list. The same reason why `[ [True], [[]], [[[]]], [[[[]]]], [[[[[]]]]] ]` is illegal.

Answer (score 2):

You have the value `[ [], [[]], [[[]]], [[[[]]]], [[[[[ ]]]]] ]`, which is a list of nested lists.

- The rightmost value is the most constrained: we know how deeply nested this list must be.
- The leftmost value is the least constrained: it is just an empty list, so it could be a list of anything.

If we apply the least constraining type to each of these, we get:

```
[
  [        ] -- [    a    ]
, [[      ]] -- [[   b   ]]
, [[[    ]]] -- [[[  c  ]]]
, [[[[  ]]]] -- [[[[ d ]]]]
, [[[[[]]]]] -- [[[[[e]]]]]
]
```

The list must have a homogenous type, so we look at unifying them. If we try to unify the first two types, `[a]` and `[[b]]`, we see that `a` ⊇ `[b]`, so we now have:

```
[
  [  ] -- [[b]]
, [[]] -- [[b]]
, ...
]
```

If we continue this process up to `[[[[d]]]]` and `[[[[[e]]]]]`, we see that `d` ⊇ `[e]`, and so we end up with:

```
[
  [        ] -- [[[[[e]]]]]
, [[      ]] -- [[[[[e]]]]]
, [[[    ]]] -- [[[[[e]]]]]
, [[[[  ]]]] -- [[[[[e]]]]]
, [[[[[]]]]] -- [[[[[e]]]]]
]
```

And so finally, the overall list has type `[[[[[[e]]]]]]`.

This is because the first element is an empty list of whatever, the second is a single-element list with an empty list of whatever, and so on. You could repeat this process *ad infinitum*, with nested singleton lists ending at a single empty list, and your type would be `[[...[a]...]]`.

So now that you know how many levels of nesting there must be before you can introduce your own type (by replacing `e`), you should be able to see why `[ [True], [[]], [[[]]], [[[[]]]], [[[[[]]]]] ]` is not valid, but `[ [], [[]], [[[]]], [[[[]]]], [[[[[True]]]]] ]` is.